# How I should remove digits with other characters (eg:100g) in R

Tags: r, character, stringr, digits

The chips column table "productWords" looks like this:
"Natural Chip SeaSalt175g"   "CCs Nacho Cheese    175g"
"Smiths Crinkle Cut Chips Chicken 170g"   "Smiths Chip Thinly S/Cream&Onion 175g"

I hope to remove **the digits and special characters**, so I use
`productWords$Chip <- str_replace_all(productWords$Chip,"[:digit:]", "")`
AND
`str_replace_all(productWords$Chip, "[[:punct:]]", " ")`

but what I want to remove is not just the digits number but "175g".

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Answer (score 1):

With `sub` you can search for a pattern and replace it (or remove it by replacing it with an empty string). The pattern in your example would be "[0-9]+g". This corresponds to *any digit*  one or more times followed by the character `g`.

```
productWords$Chip <- sub(pattern = "([0-9]+g)|[[:punct:]]", replacement = "", x = productWords$Chip)
```

Comment: You could remove punctuation in the same step if your regular expression is `"([0-9]+g)|[[:punct:]]"`